# Modelling a multivariate changepoint analysis

Tags: bayesian, change-point

I'm trying to model a multivariate multiple change point analysis.  The data I have is as follows:

Multiple sensors, positive count data, multiple change points and a time series.

For example, imagine I have a bucket of oranges with n unreliable camera sensors.  Each day I want to measure how many oranges I have based on the readings from my cameras (I don't know anything about the accuracy of the cameras - some may be good, some bad).

| . | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cam 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Cam 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Cam 3 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

I would want to identify Day 2 and Day 3 (with some uncertainty give Cam 3 disagrees).

Optional extra:
There is the additional and perhaps somewhat confusing rule that if multiple oranges are added they can only be removed one at a time.  If the oranges were added one at a time, they can all be removed at once.

For example, the following is not permitted:

| . | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $y$ | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Please help me describe the model in the usual notation, e.g.:

$\tau \sim DiscreteUniform(0, 5)$
$\lambda_1 \sim Exp()$
$\lambda_2 \sim Exp()$
$y = Poisson(\tau > \lambda_1)$

Comment: Why is your example not permitted?  I understand that the true number of oranges can't be (0,2,0,0), but can the measured number of oranges do that?  Couldn't it just be an unreliable camera with error = 2 on Day 2?

Comment: Can you write down the rule set like this?  (1) Add 1 orange with probability p1 (2) Add poisson(lambda)  + 2 oranges with probability p2 (3) for each orange in the basket from the previous time step (3i) if that orange was added in a group, delete one orange with probability p_4 and skip the rest of the group oranges (3ii) if that orange was added singlely, group it with other singlely added oranges and delete with probability p_5